# Just installed magento, can't access magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magento-connect

Just installed Magento for the first time locally on a mac via phpMyAdmin. Used this speedy 1:43 video to figure out how to do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWOW6futhVQ

The site is up locally @ http://127.0.0.1:8888/ and `/admin` is also working allowing me to login to the portal.

The next goal is to access Magento Connect Manager to download an extension but when I navigate to `System` > `Magento Connect` > `Magento Connect Manager` and then put in the same credentials used in the admin panel the result is **"Invalid user name or password"**.

One verification I've made is making sure the the `Administrators role` has `All` `Resource Access` but it's still showing the same error.

So my question is, might you know of anything that may need to be done for a fresh installation to access the Magento Connect Manager, or any ideas on how I may troubleshoot the issue?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files.

Comment: @BabyinMagento Thank you for the assistance, ended up following your direction and installing via ftp instead. Thank you!

Comment: [It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/) in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this. **Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about securit